# Как осуществить action с помощью PHP вне формы

Tags: php

Есть некая форма

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form-vidguki">
```

в которой поле action пустое, в форме есть проверка каптчи, Проверка капчти реализована на php. Если каптча введена неверно, то просто возвращает на эту же страницу(страница добавление отзыва). Если капча введена правильно, то необходимо осуществить action, после чего осуществляется передача данных из формы в файл добавления отзыва в базу, как это сделать?
Или по-другому, как осуществлять action только после проверки каптчи?

Comment: уточните вопрос  а то непонятно зачем вам другой action вызывать когда можно в этом же всё сделать.

Comment: Мне надо выполнить один единственный action, но при условии. Если поле action в форме не пустое, то данные отправляются независимо от правильности капчти

Comment: Вы изобретаете велосипед с треугольными колёсами. action у формы один и ведёт на скрипт обработки введенных данных. А уже скрипт проверяет капчу и если она верна - запихивает данные в базу. В противном случае перенаправляет в на страницу ввода.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="page.php" method="post" id="form-vidguki">
```

Форма в любом случае должна лететь на обработчик page.php в нём проверяется:
1. Полнота и правильность заполнения
2. Капча
Если правильно всё обработчик добавляет запись в БД а пользователя потом редиректит куда надо.
Если не правильно то пользователя сразу редиректим куда надо - назад, или на страницу ошибки.